# If to E/F, every irredicible poly over at F with a root in E has all its roots in E, then E/F is Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I know the converse case is right, but I don't know this case, especially I can't find or proof the separable poly over F such that E is the splitting field.

Comment: $F = \mathbf F_p (T^p)$, $E = \mathbf F_p (T)$ and $f = X^p - T^p ∈ \mathbf F_p (T^p)[X]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you've stated is that of a [normal extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension).  One definition of a Galois extension is that it's a normal and separable extension.

So, no.  While all Galois extensions are normal, not all normal extensions are Galois.

As k.stm points out in the comments $\mathbb F_p(\sqrt[p]{t})$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb F_p(t)$ (because it's the splitting field of $x = t^p$) but it's not a separable extension because the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[p]{t}$ is $x^p - t \in \mathbb F_p(t)[x]$ but in $\mathbb F_p(\sqrt[p]{t})[x]$ we have $x^p - t = (x - \sqrt[p]{t})^p$ so clearly the roots are not distinct.  So that's an example of a field extension which is normal but not Galois.

One think to note, though, is that any algebraic extension of a characteristic zero field is automatically separable.  So for such extensions normal = Galois.